# How to update properties of an object contained in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following classes:

```
class A {
    String s;
    Double d;
    A a;
}

class B {
    String s;
    Double d;
}
```

And the following ArrayLists:

```
List<A> A_list = new ArrayList<A>(); // List of A class object
List<B> B_list = new ArrayList<B>(); // List of B class object
```

All I need to do is:

```
iterate through A_list
    iterate through B_list 
        if A_list.get(i).s is equal to B_list.get(j).s
        // just update this A_list.get(i).d value without changing other properties
        then A_list.get(i).d = A_list.get(i).d + B_list.get(j).d;
```

Can somebody please suggest me (with some sample code if possible) how can I update a particular object property in an arrayList of object without changing other properties?

I am not so that much experienced in java. So pardon me if I made any mistake!

Thanks!

Comment: You alrady have the solution. `A_list.get(i).d` is the only thing that is changed ...

Comment: @hage:  will that changes preserved? isn't it require to do any A_list.set() if I got more than one B_list and try to make that update further?

Comment: The lists only save references to the objects put into them. So when you change a property of an item in a list, this change instantly persistant.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may be some help to you.

```
 for (A arr : A_list){

       for (B brr : B_list){

           if ((arr.s).equals(brr.s)){

                  arr.d = arr.d + brr.d;

      }

 }


}
```